# Why is Django 1.7 running migrations for other apps?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I've created a new migration in one of my apps, actually I've created 2 migrations now without commiting.  I'd like to merge these 2 into one migration since they are all related to the current feature I'm working on.  However I can't seem to reverse migrate from 0002 back to 0001 in the customers app because Django goes on an unmigration frenzy and starts unmigrating what seems to be all my apps!  It doesn't seem to be in the dependency list, so I'm not sure WHY it is going into a frenzy.  Anyone else seen this?

**Migrations list: (where the app stands at the moment)**

```
customers
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_customercontact_picture         # Not yet committed
 [ ] 0003_customercontact_start_on        # Want to roll it into 0002
```

**Command I'm issuing that goes runs into the ditch:**

```
python manage.py migration customers 0001
```

**Customer Migration 0002 dependencies:**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('customers', '0001_initial'),
    ]
```

**Another App Migration dependencies:  (It is unmigrating this app and others for some reason)**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('customers', '0001_initial'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you considered squashing your migrations? Seems to be more like what you're trying do do: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations

Comment: I've considered it, but since the files hadn't been committed yet, my idea was to unmigrate back to 0001, delete 0002 and 0003 and just create on migration at that point.